# Getting error trying to commit using Subversion on Mac OS X

Tags: svn, commit

Using [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29) I try to commit with:

```
 svn ci dir/filename
```

And I get this:

```
svn: system('emacs svn-commit.tmp') returned 256
```

What does this mean? How can I to fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing your primary editor is NOT emacs, or you would understand the error message right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to commit something to Subversion, it needs a commit comment. Unless you pass a commit comment on the command line (using `-m message`), Subversion will automatically launch your preferred editor. It appears that your editor is emacs, but there is a problem launching it.

Either fix emacs, or set your `EDITOR` or `SVN_EDITOR` environment variables to a different editor that actually works.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly related:  I'm seeing similar errors on `vim` when setting `SVN_EDITOR` without the qualifying the path.  From your error output, I see you have done the same with `emacs`.  Try `export SVN_EDITOR=/usr/bin/emacs`.  Doing the same with `/usr/bin/vim` eliminated the 256 status codes.

I can't explain why.  Seems like a bug to me.

See [this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Bundled-vim-in-Mac-OS-X-10-5-and-Exit-code-tp1219052p1219054.html) 2009 discussion about vim on OSX 10.5.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like svn is not able to launch emacs for editing the comments for the commit.

If you just hava a few words of comments for your commit you could use:

```
svn ci dir/filename -m "Made some small changes"
```

another option might be to use the `--editor-cmd` option of svn. see `svn help ci` for details.

Answer (score 2):

googling `svn: system('emacs svn-commit.tmp') returned 256` shows the following link as the first result.

http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2008/03/vim-weird-os-x-105-problem.html

Comment: That post you refer to is specifically a Vim plugin problem.

Comment: same problem regardless, it is an Editor problem NOT an svn problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like SVN tried to invoke emacs to allow you to edit the commit log message, and
something failed.

Workaround: use the -m flag to specify a commit message on the command line:

```
svn ci dir/filename -m "log message here"
```