# How to commit to svn when remote username differs from local?

Tags: svn, ssh, commit

I am developing on a mac and using an svn server on another machine using `svn_ssh`.
While I was able to do an initial check-in and check-out, I cannot do a commit from the command line because the system tries to use my local username `jondoe` (and prompts a password) when connecting to the remote server where my username is `johnd`.

So, how can I tell the svn+ssh to use `johnd` for my commits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Backup your changes (just changed files, you mustn't overwrite `.svn` directory)
2. Checkout again, but now using your remote username

   ```
   svn checkout svn+ssh://<ssh_username>@<svn host domain>/<server repository path>
   ```
3. Restore your changes from backup
4. Commit them

   ```
   svn commit -m 'Description'
   ```

I've just successfuly checked out and committed with different local and SSH usernames.

Comment: Thanks but it gives the error:  svn: Must give local path (not URL) as the target of a commit.  
I tried like this: svn commit -m 'Summary of changes' . svn+ssh://my-username@my-server/my-home/my-repo 
 
just using . for myfiles

Comment: ok that seems to have worked but I'll repost here if I start getting  the same error later.  I had to modify your instructions to get it to work as when I did the checkout it failed saying that 'Myapp is already a working copy for a different URL'.  so I just moved the Myapp dir to MyappXYZ and then your suggestion worked.
 
I had thought of doing it this way but was hoping not to as I suspect the error will recur  as this is pretty much the same way I originally checked out my project. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

Use `--username` option

```
svn commit --username johnd
```

Comment: Thanks but that yields another error: 
svn commit --username johnd
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: system('vim svn-commit.tmp') returned 256
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/Users/johndoe/development/Myapp/svn-commit.tmp'

Comment: @Calgacus - I have a Mac, and use the same sort of syntax to set the Subversion user name. When you give it `--username`, it should have asked for a password. You can also pass a password via the `--password` parameter. I wonder if the problem you got is with the `vim` command and not with the svn command itself. Try `svn commit --user johnd -m "commit description"` which bypasses `vim` for entering the commit message.

Comment: @Calgacus: looks like svn failed to find your default editor. Either set `EDITOR` or `SVN_EDITOR` environment variables appropriately or pass commit message by `-m` option. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2008609/72178).

Comment: If it's that easy, why some people create a dedicated system user just for committing to a svn repository?

Answer (score 3):

In your `~/.ssh/config`, add a section like this:

```
Host svn.example.com
User johnd
```

Replace `svn.example.com` with the hostname of the svn server.

This will work for all ssh connections, not just subversion-related ones.

See also the manual page `ssh_config`, which you may be able to read by running `man ssh_config` in a shell.